# When i tried to git fetch && git checkout then i got the error

Tags: git, github

This branch belongs to one of my coworkers, and when I attempted to fetch and checkout his branch, I received an error. I attempted to use git fetch and git checkout in the branch instead.

issue id: <sup>git checkout send_mailer_api_fix_15dec23 && git fetch</sup>
what I receive at the terminal is error: there was no file matching the pathspec'send_mailer_api_fix_15dec23' that Git was aware of.

Comment: You need to fetch first and then do the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the branch hasn't been pushed globally yet. Tell a colleague to push the branch first.